# Overriding generated text on the Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As part of a bunch of javascript a bunch of HTML is generated:

```
//for loop
var title = document.createElement('strong');
title.className = "titleSub";
//more add etc.
```

So this part is working correctly:

[image]

That text in there crom from a database call. All I'm trying to do is override this text:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".titleSub").Text("sss");
});
```

However, this code is not applying and the text is not updated. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it??

Comment: $(".titleSub").text("sss");  - no capital T

Comment: its `.text` not `.Text`, plus you are doing the call once the DOM is ready, have you created the element before then?

Comment: All ECMA script properties are case sensitive. Try `.text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and not `.Text()` and JavaScript is CaSe SeNsItIvE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".titleSub").text("sss");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When building the element `title`, try

```
title.innerText =  'sss';
```

Or if you wish to do after the element is inserted into the DOM

```
$('.titleSub').text('sss');
```

Comment: Good thinking, but chances are he doesn't have access to that script. If he did, why would he add the **wrong** texts in the first place?

Comment: This is true, Just wanted to highlight the difference in the answers, I just updated to include the alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try .innerText() or .innerHtml instead of .Text()

Comment: OP is using a jQuery object so it would be `.text()`, innerText/innerHTML are a properties on the actual html element and are not functions

Comment: With `jQuery`, one can only access DOM properties using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), not directly, figbomb. (i.e. setter: `$('{elementSelector}').prop('{propertyName}', '{value}')` and getter: `$('{elementSelector}').prop('{propertyName}')`